# R: Count categories in each column when not all categories appear

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

A simple `data.frame` with `character` columns:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c", "c"), y = c("a", "b", "b", "c"))
```

Suppose I wish to count the categories at each column, and fast, returning another `data.frame`. The following using `map` from `purrr` is elegant and works:

```
df %>%
  map(table) %>%
  Reduce(cbind, .) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  set_names(c("x", "y"))

  x y
a 1 1
b 1 2
c 2 1
```

HOWEVER. What to do when not all categories appear in each column? Example:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "b"), y = c("a", "a", "a"))
```

I would want the count for `b` in the `y` column to be `0`. But I get:

```
df2 %>%
  map(table) %>%
  Reduce(cbind, .) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  set_names(c("x", "y"))

  x y
a 1 3
b 2 3
```

Without even a warning! I'm guessing this is because of `cbind`'s habbit of recycling elements of one column to match the length of another. I tried using `qpcR:::cbind.na` to at least get `NA` values for the missing categories which I can later convert to `0` but I get this error:

```
Error in matrix(, maxRow - nrow(x), ncol(x)) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
```

What's a great, fast solution, preferably from the `tidyverse` set of packages?

UPDATE:

For the first case where we know all categories are in all columns:

```
df %>% dmap(function(x) as.numeric(table(x)))
```

is probably much more elegant.

Comment: In base R, the following will work. `sapply(df2, function(i) table(factor(i, levels=levels(unlist(df2)))))`. `factor` is used to include all available levels, which is contained in `levels(unlist(df2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gather()` and `spread()` from tidyr with dplyr's `count()` in the middle.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- data_frame(x = c("a", "b", "b"), y = c("a", "a", "a"))

df2 %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  count(key, value) %>%
  spread(key, n, fill = 0)
```

Result:

```
  value     x     y
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     1     3
2     b     2     0
```

The `fill = 0` in `spread()` is what causes the b/y pair to be 0.